# How to mix audio input devices in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia

I'm new to Qt's multimedia library and in my application I want to mix audio from multiple input devices (e.g. microphone), in order to stream it via TCP.

As far as I know I have to obtain the specific `QAudioDeviceInfo` for all needed devices first - together with an according `QAudioFormat` object - and use this with `QAudioInput`. Then I simply call `start()` for every created `QAudioInput` object and read out pending bytes with `readLine()`.

But how can I mix audio data of multiple devices to one buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any Qt specific method / class to do this. However it's pretty simple to do it yourself.

The most basic way (assuming you are using PCM), you can simply add the two streams/buffers together word by word (if I recall they are 16-bit PCM words).

So if you have two input buffers:

```
int16 buff1[10];
int16 buff2[10];
int16 mixBuff[10];

// Fill them...
//... code goes here to read from the buffers ....

// Add them (effectively mix them)

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   mixBuff[i] = buff1[i] + buff2[i];
}
```

Now, this is very crude and does not take any scaling into consideration. So imagine buff1 and buff2 both use 80% of the dynamic range (call this full volume, beyond which you get distortion), then when you add them together you will get number overrun (i.e. 16-bit max is 65535 so 50000 + 50000 will be a over run).

Each time you mix you effectively need half the two inputs (so 65535 / 2 + 65535 / 2 = 65535... i.e. when you add them up you can't overrun). So your mix code is like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   mixBuff[i] = (buff1[i] >> 1) + (buff2[i] >> 1);
}
```

There is much more you can do (noise removal etc...) but then the maths start getting a bit hairy. This is very simple. You can use the shift afterwards to increase / decrease volume as simple volume control if you want.

**EDIT**

One thing to note... you are using readline() (which the docs say reads the data out as ASCII). I always use read() which it does not state the "format" it is read out, but I am assuming binary. So this code may not work if you use readline() but I have never tried it. It works well for read(), you don't really want to be working in ASCII if you want to manipulate the data.

Comment: Well, after perusing your answer it looks very straightforward. Definitely gonna try this out soon. Any recommendation what buffer size I should choose? I need to stream in realtime without any delay (if possible).

Comment: I find it is a compromise  between latency (delay added waiting around for lots of data) and processing/efficiency. So if you want low latency then maybe use buffer size ~10 words (20 bytes). At 16kbps 16000 / 8 = 2000 bytes per second, so this is about 10ms so quite a short delay, but the processor will be waking up alot. I assume you are using the readReady() signal so it only wakes when there is data (i.e. you are not polling)?

Comment: Yes I do poll and I'm using `read()`. Each time an audio device has bytes available I append the data to a prime buffer, but I just fetch enough data to fill up the buffer completely before I emit an according signal to notify other classes that a new data block is available. In case the prime buffer is still at max capacity but there's pending data from the audio devices, I discard just enough data on the beginning to make room for the new data. Speaking of audio quality, I always need to stream audio data with `2 Channels`, `24 Bit Depth` and `48kHz Sample Rate`.

Comment: I did a small calc on determining needed bandwidth. `2 channels` x `24 bit` x `48kHz` are `281,25 kbyte/s` worth of data. For realtime streaming I chose a `10ms delay`, so I need to obtain a minimum of `2,81 kbytes` of data each cycle. Is this preferable?

Comment: Its probably better to connect `QIODevice signal readyRead()` to your slot. Then whenever anything is received your slot will be called (more efficient then polling). Then in your slot, you always read everything out and put it into your own buffer and then when you have enough data you send it. I would avoid filling buffers up in real time apps because you often need some leeway. Lets say your packets are 2000 bytes, then you can make your buffer 4000. Once it is > 2000 then send a packet. The code can still be very simple. If space is an issue then make everything smaller.

Comment: I would say your 10ms delay is better just because its lower latency (else you will have a 1 second delay in your system). I don't think we would notice a 10ms delay. But when you go to 10ms you don't really want to be polling... better to setup the connection (I mentioned in the last comment).

Comment: Sure, I will post some code snippets soon. Your advice using the `readyRead()` signal instead of polling only applies, if I'm using just one `QIODevice` right?, because else how do I manage to mix data of multiple devices?

Comment: For each device you just attach it to a different slot. So (just psuedo code): `connect(IODev1, signal(readyRead(), myClass, slot(dev1Slot))` and `connect(IODev2, signal(readyRead(), myClass, slot(dev2Slot))`

Comment: I added my current dev state to the threat.

Comment: Cool.. but I don't see what calls this code... when do you call the foreach loop? - is it based on a timer, or a signal or something else?

Comment: Since this is a thread class (inheriting by `QThread`) this all takes places within the `run()` method. In case an error occurs the `while` loop gets exited and the thread emits the `finished()` signal. The thread gets created as a member of the overall audio class.

Comment: ohh... you inherited qthread and reimplemented run()? This is really not how QThread is meant to be used. Also I think your code will only run once, after the foreach loop finishes it will never be called again.  I would say there are a few things to fix up here. Take a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744997/qserialport-in-qthread-run-bytesavailable-is-zero for how to implement threads corrects in Qt. You don't need (or want) to inherit QThread unless you want to change the way threads work - that's the first thing to fix up I would say :)

Comment: You know why it's called a snippet right?, because it shows only a min part of the whole code. Given code is wrapped in a while loop - that always checks for `isInterruptionRequested()` - of course. And in what way is this wrong? Why is `moveToThread()` better than my attempt? I did this in the first place because of manually stopping the thread while he's looping, and I don't want to wait for any signals of `QIODevice` objects because else I can't mix the data together properly!

Comment: Ok, well I can't see that code, I only have your description to go by : )    So, if you want to continue using the polling method that is up to you also, but you can mix the two perfectly well the other way, but involves a event driven design - which for real time is more efficient since polling sucks up your processing. I assume you have a sleep or something in your loop? .. but I think the original issue is solved so if you have further problems you should make a new post : ) If you do send me a link and post up more code (including outer loop etc...)

Comment: You're right, I better move that to another threat :) Thanks for your actual answer.

Comment: hello how can we use 'shifting' for volume control as you mentioned in answer?

Comment: @AkınYılmaz to increase / decrease the volume (and this is a crude approach, but simple and somewhat effective) you arithmetically shift each word in your stream right or left (i.e. double or half the amplitude). e.g. if you have a buffer of `uint16_t` and you want to increase volume a little bit you do `buffer[x] <<= 1` for each word in the buffer. If you want to decrease a little bit `buffer[x] >>= 1`. If you want to decrease a lot you do `buffer[x] >>= 3`...